# Oracle Firstcup tutorial (firstcup-war)

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm new into Java ee. I got a tutorial firstcup from oracle java ee page. I followed the tutorial for dukes-age and it works fine.
The tutorial for firstcup-war don't seem to run on my system.

I am using Netbeans 8.0, GlassFish 4.0 and windows 7 operating system.

**1.** I followed the instructions provided and when i run the project the
    first message I got was to add a server I did not see on the
    tutorial (firstcup-war).

**2.** After adding a glassfish server the project still wasn't deployed on
    server and i got this warnings and exceptions form the glassfish
    server:

**2.1**

```
Warning:   RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning:   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Warning:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.]
Severe:   Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0
  at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
.....

and chain of other exception that caused the above execption.
```

**2.2**

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [firstcup-war]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
.....
```

**3.**

On the run(firstcup-war) output page I got this message after the log that says build success:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.949s
Finished at: Mon Apr 21 17:05:54 WAT 2014
Final Memory: 9M/111M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetBeans: Deploying on GlassFish Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\NYE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\java ee\firstcup-war\target\firstcup-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
```

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tutorial maven only creates a war file. You have to deploy it to the glassfish server using the glassfish console.

```
http://localhost:4848
```

Also you have to start the Java Database.

```
asadmin start-database
```

Comment: this saved me too, any way to start-database through intellij idea when using glassfish as local server